# C++ "forgetting" that variable is constexpr when used as function argument

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr

I have the following code where I am irritated by the fact that compiler is unable to see that variable passed as argument to a function is constexpr so I must use arity 0 function instead of 1 argument function.

I know this is not a compiler bug, but I wonder if there are idioms that enable to workaround this problem.

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

static constexpr std::array<int, 5> arr{11, 22, 33, 44, 55};

template <typename C, typename P, typename Y>
static constexpr void copy_if(const C& rng, P p, Y yi3ld) {
    for (const auto& elem: rng) {
        if (p(elem)){
            yi3ld(elem);
        }
    }
}

// template<std::size_t N>
static constexpr auto get_evens(/* const std::array<int, N>& arr */) {
    constexpr auto is_even = [](const int i) constexpr {return i % 2 == 0;};
    constexpr int cnt = [/* &arr, */&is_even]() constexpr {
        int cnt = 0;
        auto increment = [&cnt] (const auto&){cnt++;};
        copy_if(arr, is_even, increment);
        return cnt;
    }();
    std::array<int, cnt> result{};
    int idx = 0;
    copy_if(arr, is_even, [&result, &idx](const auto& val){ result[idx++] = val;});
    return result;
}

int main() {
    // constexpr std::array<int, 5> arr{11, 22, 33, 44, 55};
    for (const int i:get_evens(/* arr */)) {
        std::cout << i << " " << std::endl;
    }
}
```

If it is not obvious what I want: I would like to change `get_evens` signature so that it is template templated on array size N and that it takes 1 argument of type `const std::array<int, N>&`.

The error message when I change `arr` to be an function argument isn't helpful:

> prog.cc:25:21: note: initializer of 'cnt' is not a constant expression
>   prog.cc:19:19: note: declared here
>       `constexpr int cnt = [&arr, &is_even]()constexpr {`

Comment: *"I know this is not a compiler bug"* - I wouldn't be certain.

Comment: Cannot reproduce with latest gcc and clang.

Comment: @evg code I pasted works, if you change it that get_evens takes array as an argument then it does not work

Comment: Then please add the code that doesn't work. Function argument itself is never `constexpr`.

Comment: https://wandbox.org/permlink/SB8Ka1voP0pCvhWR

Comment: Your example is far from a [mcve]...

Comment: I've edited your code, please check if I interpreted your intention correctly.

Comment: @Evg I am fine with arr being constexpr static, but other than that yes.

Comment: What is `yi3ld`?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont misspeled yield, since I am hoping WG21 will see the light and remove co_... As why it is used: so that the same function can be used to determine the size of the resulting array and to populate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

static constexpr std::array<int, 5> arr{11, 22, 33, 44, 55};

template <typename C, typename P, typename T>
static constexpr void invoke_if(const C& rng, P p, T target) {
    for (const auto& elem: rng) {
        if (p(elem)){
            target(elem);
        }
    }
}

constexpr bool is_even(int i) {
    return i % 2 == 0;
}

template<std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t count_evens(const std::array<int, N>& arr)
{
    std::size_t cnt = 0;
    invoke_if(arr, is_even, [&cnt](auto&&){++cnt;});
    return cnt;
}

template<std::size_t cnt, std::size_t N>
static constexpr auto get_evens(const std::array<int, N>& arr) {
    std::array<int, cnt> result{};
    int idx = 0;
    invoke_if(arr, is_even, [&result, &idx](const auto& val){ result[idx++] = val;});
    return result;
}

int main() {
    // constexpr std::array<int, 5> arr{11, 22, 33, 44, 55};
    for (const int i:get_evens<count_evens(arr)>(arr)) {
        std::cout << i << " " << std::endl;
    }
}
```

this [works in g++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/60cf6b3cce8c2b6f), but in clang we get a problem because the [`begin` on an `array` isn't properly `constexpr` with at least one library](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f0bba031d90ab94).  Or maybe g++ violates the standard and clang does not.

Comment: nit: typo at the end: i assume you mean clang does NOT

Comment: can you explain how invoke_if goes around the limit mentioned in other answers(that arr is not constexpr inside the body of function)

Comment: another note: clang 7 compiles your code https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/r2xair

Comment: @nose the trick is the code must be valid in both run and compile time contexts.  The trick is I split length from values.

Answer (score 10):

A function argument is never a constant expression, even if a function is used in `constexpr` context:

```
constexpr int foo(int i)
{
    // i is not a constexpr
    return i + 1;
}

constexpr auto i = 1;
constexpr auto j = foo(i);
```

To mimic a `constexpr` argument, use a template parameter:

```
template<int i>
constexpr int foo()
{
    // i is constexpr
    return i + 1;
}

constexpr auto i = 1;
constexpr auto j = foo<i>();
```

A possible solution is to use `std::integer_sequence` to encode integers into a type:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename P, typename Y, int... elements>
constexpr void copy_if_impl(P p, Y yi3ld, std::integer_sequence<int, elements...>) {
    ((p(elements) && (yi3ld(elements), true)), ...);
}

template<typename arr_t, typename P, typename Y>
constexpr void copy_if(P p, Y yi3ld) {
    copy_if_impl(p, yi3ld, arr_t{});
}

template<typename arr_t>
constexpr auto get_evens(){
    constexpr auto is_even = [](const int i) constexpr { return i % 2 == 0; };
    constexpr int cnt = [&is_even]() constexpr {
        int cnt = 0;
        auto increment = [&cnt](const auto&) { cnt++; };
        copy_if<arr_t>(is_even, increment);
        return cnt;
    }();

    std::array<int, cnt> result{};
    int idx = 0;
    copy_if<arr_t>(is_even, [&result, &idx](const auto& val) {
        result[idx++] = val; });
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    using arr = std::integer_sequence<int, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55>;
    for (const int i : get_evens<arr>()) {
        std::cout << i << " " << std::endl;
    }
}
```

**Addition suggested by Constantinos Glynos.**

From *Effective Modern C++* book by **Scott Meyers**, item 15, p.98:

> - `constexpr` functions can be used in contexts that demand compile-time constants. If the values of the arguments you pass to a `constexpr` function in such a context are known during compilation, the result will be computed during compilation. If any of the arguments’ values is not known during compilation, your code will be rejected.
> - When a `constexpr` function is called with one or more values that are not known during compilation, it acts like a normal function, computing its result at runtime. This means you don’t need two functions to perform the same operation, one for compile-time constants and one for all other values. The `constexpr` function does it all.

Comment: upvoted.I hope somebody comes up with a nicer hack, but I doubt it... So I will probably accept your answer in the end. :)

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl, take a look at `std::integer_sequence`. Probably, you can use it here instead of `std::array`.

Comment: The problem of making `arr` a template parameter is that this won't work for local `constexpr` arrays.

Comment: @Holt, I don't suggest to make `arr` itself a template parameter, some workaround is needed. I just demonstrated the principle.

Comment: @Evg Then you have to extend your answer. As it is, you simply points out the problem and provides an answer for a very simplified version of the original problem, which is hard to extend to the actual problem.

Comment: @Evg: Can I edit your answer to add some text from Scott Meyer's Modern C++ book? I think he explains this too.

Comment: @ConstantinosGlynos it may be better to provide separate answer. Hard to know without knowing what yo uwant to write

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: I was about to, but I didn't want to repeat what Evg has already said. It's pretty much the same code and I like his simplified example. I just felt that the answer could use a bit more backup from a book reference.

Comment: @Evg: No worries! :-) Did you see the quotes from the book?

Comment: @ConstantinosGlynos, your edit was rejected automatically because of my edit, so I added it myself. Thanks!

Comment: " If the values of the arguments you pass to a constexpr function in such a context are known during compilation, the result will be computed during compilation." is exactly the opposite of the situation in this question. :D

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl, not entirely so. You can pass `std::array` as an argument and get `constexpr` result, but inside the function this array is not `constexpr` itself. I would say that this citation being correct does not explain the source of the problem.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl A lots of people are misguided regarding `constexpr` functions. If a function `F` is `constexpr`, `F(x)` can be evaluated at compile time if `x` is already a constant expression, but `F(x)` will be evaluated at runtime if `x` is only available at runtime, so within `F`, you cannot consider `x` as a constant expression. Only the result of `F(x)` can be considered a constant expression.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer has a correct work around but I think the reasoning has nothing to do with parameters but instead to do with the lambda capture here:

```
constexpr int cnt = [/* &arr, */&is_even]()
```

Indeed we can test the various scenarios with this code:

```
#include <array> 
#include <iostream>

template <size_t N>
constexpr int foo(const std::array<int, N>& arr) {
    return [&arr] () { return arr.size(); }();
}

template <size_t N>
constexpr int bar(const std::array<int, N>& arr) {
    int res{};
    for (auto i : arr) {
        res++;
    }
    return res;
}

template <size_t N>
constexpr int baz(const std::array<int, N>& arr)     {
    constexpr int test = [&arr] () constexpr {
        return bar(arr);
    }();
    return test;
}

int main() {
    constexpr std::array<int, 5> arr{11, 22, 33, 44, 55};
    constexpr std::array<int, foo(arr)> test{};
    constexpr std::array<int, bar(arr)> test2{};
    constexpr std::array<int, baz(arr)> test3{};
}
```

Note that the line where `test3` is initialized fails to compile. This, however, compiles just fine:

```
template <size_t N>
constexpr int baz(const std::array<int, N>& arr) {
    return bar(arr);
}
```

So, what's the problem here? Well lambdas are really just glorified functors, and internally it'll look something like this:

```
struct constexpr_functor {
    const std::array<int, 5>& arr;
    constexpr constexpr_functor(const std::array<int, 5>& test)
        : arr(test) { }
    constexpr int operator()() const {
        return bar(arr);
    }
};
// ...
constexpr constexpr_functor t{arr};
constexpr std::array<int, t()> test3{};
```

Notice now that we get an error message showing the real problem:

```
test.cpp:36:33: note: reference to 'arr' is not a constant expression
test.cpp:33:34: note: declared here
    constexpr std::array<int, 5> arr{11, 22, 33, 44, 55};
```

The other answer quotes Scotts Meyer's book but misinterprets the quotes. The book actually shows several examples of parameters being used in constexpr situations, but the quotes are simply saying that if you pass a non-constexpr parameter, the function can run at compile-time.

Comment: I don't see why lambdas are important here. What you can't do is this: `constexpr void foo(int i) { std:array<int, i> arr; }`. But this is essentially what OP is doing, `cnt` playing the role of `i`. The quotation from Scotts Meyer's book is not very relevant for the answer itself indeed.

Comment: The problem is not the lambda, the problem is the use of `cnt` as a constant expression **within** `get_evens()`. All your examples will fail to compile if you try to use the result of the expression within the function themselves. Why? Because a `constexpr` function must be valid for `constexpr` but also non-`constexpr` arguments. The problem in OP's code is that `cnt` is the result of a computation involving `arr`, i.e., we could write `int cnt = f(arr);`, whatever `f` is (`constexpr` or not). [...]

Comment: [...] Using `cnt` in a constant expression would imply that we can compute `f(arr)` at compile time, which cannot be guaranteed if `arr` is a parameter, since you cannot force functions to only accept `constexpr` arguments. The only way to do so is this pass these arguments as template parameters, which can be done in some cases, but has some limitations.

Answer (score 2):

Following the Evg's suggestion, so passing the numbers as template parameters of a `std::integer_sequence`, but passing the integer sequence as argument of the `get_evens()` function, and not as template parameter, you can use the numbers directly inside `get_evens()`.

I mean... you can simplify the `get_evens()` as follows (**EDIT**: further simplified following a suggestion from Evg (Thanks!))

```
template <typename T, T ... Ts>
constexpr auto get_evens (std::integer_sequence<T, Ts...> const &)
 {
   std::array<T, (std::size_t(!(Ts & T{1})) + ...)> result{};

   std::size_t idx = 0;

   ((void)(Ts & 1 || (result[idx++] = Ts, true)), ...);

   return result;
 }
```

and you can use it this way

```
int main()
 {
   using arr = std::integer_sequence<int, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55>;

   for ( const int i : get_evens(arr{}) )
      std::cout << i << " " << std::endl;
 }
```

Comment: Very nice simplification. My suggestions: 1) remove `const &`, 2) `constexpr std::size_t cnt = (!!(Ts & 1) + ...);` or `((Ts % 2 == 0) + ...);`.

Comment: @Evg - Point 2: D'oh! I can't understand how I did't think about it myself. It's the simpler application of C++17 folding. Thanks. Point 1: do you mean the `const &` for the `get_evens()` arguments? Why do you think is better without `const &`?

Comment: `std::integer_sequence` is an empty `struct`, its size is 1 byte, there is no point in passing it by reference. Optimizer will take care of it anyway, but it's less to type.

Answer (score 1):

```
template<auto t0, auto...ts>
struct ct_array:
  std::array<decltype(t0) const, 1+sizeof...(ts)>,
  std::integer_sequence<decltype(t0), t0, ts...>
{
  ct_array():std::array<decltype(t0) const, 1+sizeof...(ts)>{{t0, ts...}} {};
};

template<class target, auto X>
struct push;
template<auto X>
struct push<void, X>{using type=ct_array<X>;};
template<auto...elems, auto X>
struct push<ct_array<elems...>, X>{using type=ct_array<elems...,X>;};
template<class target, auto X>
using push_t= typename push<target, X>::type;

template<class target>
struct pop;
template<auto x>
struct pop<ct_array<x>>{using type=void;};
template<auto x0, auto...xs>
struct pop<ct_array<x0, xs...>>{using type=ct_array<xs...>;};
template<class target>
using pop_t=typename pop<target>::type;

template<class lhs, class rhs, class F, class=void>
struct transcribe;
template<class lhs, class rhs, class F>
using transcribe_t = typename transcribe<lhs, rhs, F>::type;

template<auto l0, auto...lhs, class rhs, class F>
struct transcribe<ct_array<l0, lhs...>, rhs, F,
  std::enable_if_t<F{}(l0) && sizeof...(lhs)>
>:
  transcribe<pop_t<ct_array<l0, lhs...>>, push_t<rhs, l0>, F>
{};
template<auto l0, auto...lhs, class rhs, class F>
struct transcribe<ct_array<l0, lhs...>, rhs, F,
  std::enable_if_t<!F{}(l0) && sizeof...(lhs)>
>:
  transcribe<pop_t<ct_array<l0, lhs...>>, rhs, F>
{};
template<auto lhs, class rhs, class F>
struct transcribe<ct_array<lhs>, rhs, F, void>
{
  using type=std::conditional_t< F{}(lhs), push_t<rhs, lhs>, rhs >;
};
template<class lhs, class F>
using filter_t = transcribe_t<lhs, void, F>;

// C++20
//auto is_even = [](auto i)->bool{ return !(i%2); };
struct is_even_t {
  template<class T>
  constexpr bool operator()(T i)const{ return !(i%2); }
};
constexpr is_even_t is_even{};

template<auto...is>
static constexpr auto get_evens(ct_array<is...>) {
  return filter_t< ct_array<is...>, decltype(is_even) >{};
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/14a0482fa9831386).

Test code:

```
auto arr = ct_array<11, 22, 33, 44, 55>{};
for (const int i : get_evens(arr)) {
    std::cout << i << " " << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Is it really necessary to make `ct_array` inherits from `std::integer_sequence` in this case? And small issue but this code does not compile in the filtered array is empty.

Comment: @holt true, because I wanted to deduce the type; I could make the type explicit or something, and use the auto detect for a factory template.  Integer sequence derivation lets you use it in other compile time contexts.